# Spring Cloud Gateway how to get original url when using forward://

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to route some requests to my local controller into the Spring Cloud Gateway and process them.
I need path part of the original url to process the request. as documentation states:

> If the url has a forward scheme (ie forward:///localendpoint), it will use the Spring DispatcherHandler to handler the request. **The path part of the request URL will be overridden with the path in the forward URL**. The unmodified original url is **appended to the list in the ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_URL_ATTR attribute.**

When I read this attribute into my controller, I'm not  getting the original url (`http://somedomain.com/data_I_need/ping`) but already modified one:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/expireProlong/",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> expireProlong(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    exchange.getAttributes().forEach( (s, o) -> System.out.println(s+" = "+o));
    return Mono.just("OK");
}
```

These are logs

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingHandler = com.xxxx.gateway.controller.Controller#expireProlong(ServerWebExchange)
//Here should be the original url `http://somedomain.com/data_I_need/ping
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.gatewayOriginalRequestUrl = [http://localhost:8182/expireProlong/]
org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingPattern = /expireProlong/
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.gatewayHandlerMapper = RoutePredicateHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.producibleMediaTypes = [application/json]
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.gatewayRequestUrl = forward:/expireProlong/
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.uriTemplateVariables = {}
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.routeWeight = {}
org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.uriTemplateVariables = {}
org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange.LOG_ID = 238ba20f
org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.matrixVariables = {}
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.gatewayRoute = Route{id='ExpireProlong', uri=forward:///expireProlong/, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/**/ping], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath /(?<remaining>.*)/ping = '/expireProlong/${remaining}'], order = 1]], metadata={}}
```

This is my spring cloud config

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: ExpireProlong
          predicates:
            - Path=/**/ping
          uri: forward:///expireProlong/
```

As you see the the original URL shows the modified URL

> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.gatewayOriginalRequestUrl=[http://localhost:8182/expireProlong/]

So what is the correct way to get original url data when using`forward://`scheme routing?